# Having an issue with the Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0 error, but not sure why it is happening

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am currently having an issue where I am getting the Error:

> Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0.

I am declaring the database variables in a separate file

```
module.exports = {
    HOST: "localhost",
    USER: "sp_admin",
    PASSWORD: "*******",
    DB: "db_splvl4",
    SCHEMA: "qu_mgr",
    dialect: "postgres",
    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000
    }
};
```

Which is fine and not having any issues with that, in the details of the exception I am pointed to the line and column of 2 different files.

> at Object. (F:\Software\Development\Project\Proof-of-Concept\app\models\index.js:4:19)

> at Object. (F:\Software\Development\Project\Proof-of-Concept\server.js:5:12)

Starting with the first index.js

```
const config = require("../config/db.config.js");

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize(         <---- on this line
    config.DB,
    config.SCHEMA,
    config.USER,
    config.PASSWORD,
    {
        host: config.HOST,
        dialect: config.dialect,
        operatorsAliases: false,

        pool: {
            max: config.pool.max,
            min: config.pool.min,
            acquire: config.pool.acquire,
            idle: config.pool.idle
        }
    }
);

const db = {};

db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;

db.user = require("../models/user.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.role = require("../models/role.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);

db.role.belongsToMany(db.user, {
    through: "user_roles",
    foreignKey: "roleId",
    otherKey: "userId"
});
db.user.belongsToMany(db.role, {
    through: "user_roles",
    foreignKey: "userId",
    otherKey: "roleId"
});

db.ROLES = ["user", "admin", "moderator"];

module.exports = db;
```

And with the second server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const db = require("./app/models");    <--- Here on this line
const Role = db.role;

var corsOptions = {
    origin: "http://localhost:8081"
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// This is used for application/json content parsing
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// This is used for application/x-www-form-urlencoded content parsing
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

db.sequelize.sync({ force: true }).then(() => {
    console.log('Drop and Resync Database with { force: true }');
    initial();
});
```

The /app/models is pointing to the models/index.js

When I ran this originally I was presented with a rejectedpromise, but this was due to it not seeing any tables as they are part of a schema.

So I added the schema variable to the config file and referenced it where I believe that it would need referencing, but now I am being faced with the dialect error.

I have searched through and seen that other people have faced this problem, but the fixes presented to them don't fix my issues, any help will be greatly appreciated.